# Why does solving this equation with differential equations and related rates yield different results?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, related-rates

[image]
Sorry for the figure being so large I was unsure how to shrink it.

The question asked is about a beam anchored at angle $\theta$ to two perpendicular axes (at points a and b). The beam slides along them at a constant speed $-V$ in the $x$ direction and $V_b$ in the $y$ direction. The goal is to solve for $V_b$ in terms of $\theta$ and $V$. I solved this equation in two different ways, the first using related rates and the second using a differential equation, and don't understand why they yield different results, and I was hoping someone could shed some light on it for me, as I think I violated some mathematical rule when solving with related rates.

Solve attempt 1 using related rates:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -v\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &= v_b\\
y &=x\tan\theta\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} &=\tan\theta\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &=-v\tan\theta\\
v_b &=-v\tan\theta
\end{align*}

Solve attempt 2 using differential equations (where $L$ is the beam)

\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2 &=L^2\\
2x\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+2y\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} &=0\\
-2xv+2yv_b &=0\\
v_b &=\frac{x}{y}v\\
v_b &=\frac{v}{\tan\theta}
\end{align*}

Comment: In attempt 1, your third line is $y=x\tan\theta$ but your fourth line is $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\tan\theta$.  Note that $\frac{y}{x}\ne\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: so are you saying the derivative of $y=xtanθ$ with respect to x is not $tanθ$?

Comment: If you claim that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\tan\theta$, then you are claiming that $\tan\theta$ is a constant.  But it isn't; it depends on $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempt 1, you cannot deduce $\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan\theta$ from the equation $y=x\tan\theta$, because $\theta$ is also a function of $x$. You should instead deduce $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from the equation
$$x^2+y^2=L^2.\tag1$$
Implicit differentiation of (1) wrt $x$ gives
$$2x + 2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0,$$
which yields $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac xy$. When you plug this value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ into
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt},$$
you will end up with the same result as in attempt 2.